# 'atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size' doesn't map to a List object: 150

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, apache-atlas

I tried to setup the sqoop-hook with Atlas Following these steps :

1- Set-up Atlas hook in sqoop-site.xml:

```
<property>
     <name>sqoop.job.data.publish.class</name>
     <value>org.apache.atlas.sqoop.hook.SqoopHook</value>
   </property>
```

2- copy contents of folder apache-atlas-sqoop-hook to hook/sqoop

3- copy atlas-application.properties to sqoop-conf-dir

4- copy all jars in /hook/sqoop in sqoop-dir/lib

But when I tried to execute sqoop import command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://server/db --username user -P --table tab --hive-import --create-hive-table
```

I got the following error:

```
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Setting atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size = 150
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Setting atlas.graph.index.search.solr.wait-searcher = false
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache = true
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.tx-cache-size = 15000
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO atlas.ApplicationProperties: Property (set to default) atlas.graph.cache.tx-dirty-size = 120
22/08/01 16:44:51 INFO hook.AtlasHook: Failed to load application properties
org.apache.atlas.AtlasException: Failed to load application properties
        at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:155)
        at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:108)
        at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook.<clinit>(AtlasHook.java:82)
        at org.apache.atlas.sqoop.hook.SqoopHook.<clinit>(SqoopHook.java:86)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.PublishJobData.publishJobData(PublishJobData.java:46)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:284)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.PostgresqlManager.importTable(PostgresqlManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:520)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConversionException: 'atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size' doesn't map to a List object: 150, a java.lang.Integer
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getList(AbstractConfiguration.java:1144)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getList(AbstractConfiguration.java:1109)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.interpolatedConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1274)
        at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:150)
        ... 17 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.atlas.sqoop.hook.SqoopHook.<clinit>(SqoopHook.java:86)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.PublishJobData.publishJobData(PublishJobData.java:46)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:284)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.PostgresqlManager.importTable(PostgresqlManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:520)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook.<clinit>(AtlasHook.java:87)
        ... 15 more
```

Here is the atlas-application.properties file :

```
#########  Graph Database Configs  #########

# Graph Database

#Configures the graph database to use.  Defaults to JanusGraph
#atlas.graphdb.backend=org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase

# Graph Storage
# Set atlas.graph.storage.backend to the correct value for your desired storage
# backend. Possible values:
#
# hbase
# cassandra
# embeddedcassandra - Should only be set by building Atlas with  -Pdist,embedded-cassandra-solr
# berkeleyje
#
# See the configuration documentation for more information about configuring the various  storage backends.
#
atlas.graph.storage.backend=hbase2
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.table=apache_atlas_janus
# atlas.graph.storage.username=
# atlas.graph.storage.password=
#atlas.graph.cache.db-cache=false

atlas.graph.cache.db-cache = true
atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
atlas.graph.cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
atlas.graph.cache.tx-cache-size = 15000
atlas.graph.cache.tx-dirty-size = 120

#Hbase
#For standalone mode , specify localhost
#for distributed mode, specify zookeeper quorum here
atlas.graph.storage.hostname=localhost
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.regions-per-server=1

# Gremlin Query Optimizer
#
# Enables rewriting gremlin queries to maximize performance. This flag is provided as
# a possible way to work around any defects that are found in the optimizer until they
# are resolved.
#atlas.query.gremlinOptimizerEnabled=true

# Delete handler
#
# This allows the default behavior of doing "soft" deletes to be changed.
#
# Allowed Values:
# org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v1.SoftDeleteHandlerV1 - all deletes are "soft" deletes
# org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v1.HardDeleteHandlerV1 - all deletes are "hard" deletes
#
#atlas.DeleteHandlerV1.impl=org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v1.SoftDeleteHandlerV1

# Entity audit repository
#
# This allows the default behavior of logging entity changes to hbase to be changed.
#
# Allowed Values:
# org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.HBaseBasedAuditRepository - log entity changes to hbase
# org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.CassandraBasedAuditRepository - log entity changes to cassandra
# org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.NoopEntityAuditRepository - disable the audit repository
#
atlas.EntityAuditRepository.impl=org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.HBaseBasedAuditRepository

# if Cassandra is used as a backend for audit from the above property, uncomment and set the following
# properties appropriately. If using the embedded cassandra profile, these properties can remain
# commented out.
# atlas.EntityAuditRepository.keyspace=atlas_audit
# atlas.EntityAuditRepository.replicationFactor=1


# Graph Search Index
atlas.graph.index.search.backend=solr5

#Solr
#Solr cloud mode properties
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=cloud
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=localhost:2181
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-connect-timeout=60000
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-session-timeout=60000
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.wait-searcher=false

#Solr http mode properties
#atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=http
#atlas.graph.index.search.solr.http-urls=http://localhost:8983/solr

# Solr-specific configuration property
atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size=150

#########  Import Configs  #########
#atlas.import.temp.directory=/temp/import

#########  Notification Configs  #########
atlas.notification.embedded=false
atlas.kafka.data=${sys:atlas.home}/data/kafka
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:9026
atlas.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9027
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=400
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=200
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.sync.time.ms=20
atlas.kafka.auto.commit.interval.ms=1000
atlas.kafka.hook.group.id=atlas

atlas.kafka.enable.auto.commit=false
atlas.kafka.auto.offset.reset=earliest
atlas.kafka.session.timeout.ms=30000
atlas.kafka.offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
atlas.kafka.poll.timeout.ms=1000

atlas.notification.create.topics=true
atlas.notification.replicas=1
atlas.notification.topics=ATLAS_HOOK,ATLAS_ENTITIES
atlas.notification.log.failed.messages=true
atlas.notification.consumer.retry.interval=500
atlas.notification.hook.retry.interval=1000
# Enable for Kerberized Kafka clusters
#atlas.notification.kafka.service.principal=kafka/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM
#atlas.notification.kafka.keytab.location=/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.service.keytab

## Server port configuration
#atlas.server.http.port=21000
#atlas.server.https.port=21443

#########  Security Properties  #########

# SSL config
atlas.enableTLS=false

#truststore.file=/path/to/truststore.jks
#cert.stores.credential.provider.path=jceks://file/path/to/credentialstore.jceks

#following only required for 2-way SSL
#keystore.file=/path/to/keystore.jks

# Authentication config

atlas.authentication.method.kerberos=false
atlas.authentication.method.file=true

#### ldap.type= LDAP or AD
atlas.authentication.method.ldap.type=none

#### user credentials file
atlas.authentication.method.file.filename=${sys:atlas.home}/conf/users-credentials.properties

### groups from UGI
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ugi-groups=true

######## LDAP properties #########
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.url=ldap://<ldap server url>:389
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.userDNpattern=uid={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.groupSearchBase=dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.groupSearchFilter=(member=uid={0},ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com)
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.groupRoleAttribute=cn
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.base.dn=dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.bind.dn=cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.bind.password=<password>
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.referral=ignore
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.user.searchfilter=(uid={0})
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.default.role=<default role>


######### Active directory properties #######
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.domain=example.com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.url=ldap://<AD server url>:389
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.base.dn=(sAMAccountName={0})
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.bind.dn=CN=team,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.bind.password=<password>
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.referral=ignore
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.user.searchfilter=(sAMAccountName={0})
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.default.role=<default role>

#########  JAAS Configuration ########

#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.loginModuleName = com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.loginModuleControlFlag = required
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.useKeyTab = true
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.storeKey = true
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.serviceName = kafka
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.keyTab = /etc/security/keytabs/atlas.service.keytab
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.principal = atlas/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM

#########  Server Properties  #########
atlas.rest.address=http://localhost:21000
# If enabled and set to true, this will run setup steps when the server starts
#atlas.server.run.setup.on.start=false

#########  Entity Audit Configs  #########
atlas.audit.hbase.tablename=apache_atlas_entity_audit
atlas.audit.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=1000
atlas.audit.hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost:2181

#########  High Availability Configuration ########
atlas.server.ha.enabled=false
#### Enabled the configs below as per need if HA is enabled #####
#atlas.server.ids=id1
#atlas.server.address.id1=localhost:21000
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.retry.sleeptime.ms=1000
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.num.retries=3
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=20000
## if ACLs need to be set on the created nodes, uncomment these lines and set the values ##
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.acl=<scheme>:<id>
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.auth=<scheme>:<authinfo>



######### Atlas Authorization #########
atlas.authorizer.impl=simple
atlas.authorizer.simple.authz.policy.file=atlas-simple-authz-policy.json

#########  Type Cache Implementation ########
# A type cache class which implements
# org.apache.atlas.typesystem.types.cache.TypeCache.
# The default implementation is org.apache.atlas.typesystem.types.cache.DefaultTypeCache which is a local in-memory type cache.
#atlas.TypeCache.impl=

#########  Performance Configs  #########
#atlas.graph.storage.lock.retries=10
#atlas.graph.storage.cache.db-cache-time=120000

#########  CSRF Configs  #########
atlas.rest-csrf.enabled=true
atlas.rest-csrf.browser-useragents-regex=^Mozilla.*,^Opera.*,^Chrome.*
atlas.rest-csrf.methods-to-ignore=GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,TRACE
atlas.rest-csrf.custom-header=X-XSRF-HEADER

############ KNOX Configs ################
#atlas.sso.knox.browser.useragent=Mozilla,Chrome,Opera
#atlas.sso.knox.enabled=true
#atlas.sso.knox.providerurl=https://<knox gateway ip>:8443/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso
#atlas.sso.knox.publicKey=

############ Atlas Metric/Stats configs ################
# Format: atlas.metric.query.<key>.<name>
atlas.metric.query.cache.ttlInSecs=900
#atlas.metric.query.general.typeCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.typeUnusedCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.entityCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.tagCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.entityDeleted=
#
#atlas.metric.query.entity.typeEntities=
#atlas.metric.query.entity.entityTagged=
#
#atlas.metric.query.tags.entityTags=

#########  Compiled Query Cache Configuration  #########

# The size of the compiled query cache.  Older queries will be evicted from the cache
# when we reach the capacity.

#atlas.CompiledQueryCache.capacity=1000

# Allows notifications when items are evicted from the compiled query
# cache because it has become full.  A warning will be issued when
# the specified number of evictions have occurred.  If the eviction
# warning threshold <= 0, no eviction warnings will be issued.

#atlas.CompiledQueryCache.evictionWarningThrottle=0


#########  Full Text Search Configuration  #########

#Set to false to disable full text search.
#atlas.search.fulltext.enable=true

#########  Gremlin Search Configuration  #########

#Set to false to disable gremlin search.
atlas.search.gremlin.enable=false


########## Add http headers ###########

#atlas.headers.Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
#atlas.headers.Access-Control-Allow-Methods=GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,POST
#atlas.headers.<headerName>=<headerValue>


#########  UI Configuration ########

atlas.ui.default.version=v1

atlas.hook.sqoop.synchronous=false  
atlas.hook.sqoop.numRetries=3       
atlas.hook.sqoop.queueSize=10000
```

Any Solutions Please

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've added the configuration file with the question

Comment: Seems like the error is caused by `AbstractConfiguration.getList` method against a value that actually is an integer. In which case, that is a bug that should be reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ATLAS/issues  ... Also worth pointing out that Sqoop is a retired Apache project, and ideally shouldnt be used anymore